# How to get LocalDateTime one month before

Tags: java

I am getting current date/time like this:

```
String now = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:ss:mm"));
```

How can I get the date/time one month before this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)?  I go there, I scroll down a little bit, and oh look, the [`minusMonths()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minusMonths(long)) method seems relevant.  "Returns a copy of this `LocalDateTime` with the specified number of months subtracted."  I don't mean to come across as cold, but you've got to learn where to find these things on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your code this way using `minusMonths` function

```java
String now = LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:ss:mm"));
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths( 1 ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:ss:mm" ) )
```

Reformatted:

```java
ZonedDateTime
    .now()
    .minusMonths( 1 )
    .format( 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:ss:mm" ) 
    )
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nymvjT).

> 27.08.2021 07:47:18

## Avoid `LocalDateTime.now()`

[`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class is not appropriate here as it purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do.

## `ZonedDateTime`

To capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneID z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Perhaps you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneID z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Subtract your month.

```
ZonedDateTime aMonthAgo = now.minusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do `minusMonths()` operation for achieving your desired result.

```
final String localDate =
        LocalDateTime.now()
            .minusMonths(1)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:ss:mm"));
```